# Angular: data not passing from controller to directive using isloated scope

Tags: angularjs

The question title explain my problem i want to send data from a controller to directive so i can use the data in the directive controller or view.
Here is the controller code:

```
$scope.following = product.vendorId.isUserFollowing;
```

In the controller view:

```
<vas-follow following="{{following}}"></vas-follow>
```

`following` the property am trying to pass to the directive, the directive code:

```
.directive('vasFollow', vasFollow);
    function vasFollow() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: "EA",
            scope: {
                following: '@'
            },
            link: link,
            controller: vasFollowCtrl,
            templateUrl: 'templates/directives/vasFollow.html',
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
          /* */
        };
    }
```

I tried first to use the `following` like so `{{following}}` in the directive view but it's not passing, also it is undefined in the directive controller.

I have read a lot of slimier issues but, i couldn't conclude why am having this problem.

Comment: What sort of data is `following`? Using the `@` scope binding only works with strings. Perhaps you want `=` instead and `following="following"`

Comment: it is a string actually i tried to do this in the controller 
```$scope.following = "following"``` note i also tried ```=```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `ng-model` for directive instead of your own replacement for it
2. Remove `{{}}` from assignment to share link to variable instead of just evaluated value

And please, use div or common DOM element instead of exact naming directive - it have side-effects in I.E.

Comment: I can see the point to use ```ng-model``` and, why would i remove the ```{{}}``` if am not evaluating an expression !!also am deploying the app only on chrome

Comment: NgModel already evaling it for you and provide ngModelController that allows you to handle it with amazing precise